# Mysqli missing after MAMP Update

Tags: php, apache, mamp

So i just updated my MAMP Installation to the latest Version.
Before everything worked fine, now the database connection is not working because it tells my  mysqli is missing.
The php.ini for 8.1 is the same as bevore and has this in it:

```
extension=php_mysqli.dll
```

The extension dir is also unchanged:

```
extension_dir = "C:\MAMP\bin\php\php8.1.0\ext\"
```

Also the MAMP launcher app no longer has a config tab. I can just start and stop the server.

So whats going on here?

#### Update

When starting a PHP server like this:

```
php -S 127.0.0.1:8000 -t .
```

I also have access to the Database when calling http://127.0.0.1:8000/ ....??

Comment: What _exact_ error message are you getting?

Comment: It depens which app is trying to access the DB. PMA for example tells `cannot load mysql extension`